# Prove that for all rational number $a$ and $b$, $\frac{a+b}{2}$ ≥ $\sqrt{ab}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that for all rational numbers (can be integer) a y b, $\frac{a+b}{2}$ ≥ $\sqrt{ab}$

Comment: Do you have anything in terms of an attempt?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means

Comment: are $a,b\ge0$? If not, then this isn't true.

Comment: The inequality holds for appropriate *real* numbers, not merely *rational* numbers.

Comment: AM/GM/HM${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$(a+b)^2\ge4ab\iff (a-b)^2\ge0$$

It is important $\;a,b\;$ non-negative
...

Answer (score 0):

by squaring and rearranging we get $$(a-b)^2\geq 0$$ which is true.